# How to create a "Game Option/Pause Screen" in Swing?

Tags: java, swing

Background: Making a game in Swing. It is simple turn base game. Not a whole lot going on. Because of this I didn't think I would need to implement a Game Tick. Rather, my thought was when a component got changed or needed to be updated just simply revalidate/repaint that component on the fly rather than repainting the whole screen.

I have a GameJPanel which currently has all the components on it. This JPanel is the one that contains the components that get revalidated/repainted etc.
I figured I could make JLayeredPane that holds GameJPanel and my OptionJPanel. Have a Button on GameJPanel that when pressed causes the OptionJPanel to show on top of it and having its JPanel 50% transparent (so it gives the affect it dims the GameJPanel).

However, once I did this what happened was that the GameJPanel started to replace OptionJPanel components (because of the events... etc; repainting of the components).

So currently I am at a loss on what to do. I'm thinking if I had some sort of game tick I wouldn't be having this issue, however, I am not 100% certain. I'm a little worried if I implemented a gametick that the events in game will cause the GameJPanel components to show through for half a second then get replaced. There are some events that cause components to repaint themselves without manually doing it (like quick example for JLabel setText();)

[image]
As an example of what I'm trying to go for.

I have tried with a CardLayout but I couldn't figure out how to have the OptionJPanel be on top of GameJPanel while seeing GameJPanel in the background (I tried setting background color, setOpaque(false)..., tried to limit Option JPanel size but I think the CardLayout stretches it (not 100% sure)) all I got was a gray background when doing so.

I would prefer not to go the CardLayout route because in the future I also plan on placing components on top of the GameJPanel (like someone clicks a button, have another panel on a different layer have a component slide in or out etc).
I use CardLayout a ton with my other components in GameJPanel to swap screens around, but haven't had the need to have the other components behind the one showing to show through.

Any ideas on how to go about this would be great or even example code that shows this.

Comment: You need a modal [`JDialog`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for the "pop-up" options menu. If you want specific help post a [mcve].

Comment: I should had stated I need this all to be done in the same window/JFrame (pretty sure JDialog creates a new window). I'm more so looking for advice/ideas than code but maybe later I could setup what I have attempted.

Comment: Why do you have to do it in the same window? How will the user know the implementation details?

Comment: So you are suggesting to create a JDialog that hovers over the JFrame, that has a transparent background, and be the container for the OptionJPanel?

It sounds possible; I personally haven't messed with JDialogs enough to know if it is. However, there has to be an easier way of going about it. Also, how would such an implementation look on different platforms is what worries me too.

And with this implementation it doesn't help me in the future when I what components to have animation on top of the GameJPanel etc...

Comment: This is a standard use of `JDialog`s, what's not easy about it? What can be made easier? Implementation will look the same provided you use a cross-platform L&F like the default one. What do you want to animate and why would it matter for the dialog?

Comment: Well it just seems like a lot of work. I would have to size the JDialog to the JFrame, setup a listener so they both stay the same size and on top of each other also have the JDialog move with JFrame if the user moves the screen/resizes it.

If my components were static and never really changed I could do this really simple with JLayeredPane but because of the events that cause the repainting of the components I can't have any static layers above the GameJPanel layer. I can easily think of animating stuff with JLayeredPane but with JDialogs I can't really think of how to go about it.

Comment: `"I would have to size the JDialog to the JFrame"` -- What? Why? No, you let the JDialog size *itself* to its natural size based on the preferred sizes of its constituent components and its layout manager actions. Everything else you're mentioning is a gross over-complication of things and suggests that you don't yet have a deep understand use of these dialogs (or Swing for that matter). Just try it.

Comment: As said, the dialog computes its own size (you can give ti hints). You also set it to the center of the frame, remove its decorations (top bar) and make it modal (blocks interaction with the parent). That's it. Animations is something else which is irrelevant for the dialog or other components.

Comment: Yeah learned a lot. I appreciate you guys taking the time to answer my post. I obviously never had the thought of combining JDialog and GlassPane and also haven't ran into setLocationRelativeTo method and setUndecorated method so yeah more you know. user1803551 make a lot more sense now and again appreciate everyone for the help.

Comment: You can look at the JavaDocs for the components and see if what you want to do is supported directly, I think that's the easiest approach. Enjoy!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As noted above, you would use a JDialog, a component that is easy to make (similar to making a JFrame) and easy to place. Simply place it "relative-to" the JFrame, e.g.,

```
myDialog.setLocationRelativeTo(myJFrame);
```

... and it will automatically center itself on the JFrame. The tricky part is dimming the underlying JFrame, and for this you would need to use a JGlassPane added to the JFrame's rootpane, one set with a background color that uses an alpha composite value. The tricky part with this is to draw the darker background without causing side effects, and to do this, please read Rob Camick's (StackOverflow user [camickr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/131872/camickr)) excellent tutorial on drawing in Swing with alpha composites which you can find here: [Java Tips Weblog: Backgrounds with Transparency](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/31/backgrounds-with-transparency/)

An example of such a program is shown here:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dialog.ModalityType;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

public class DialogEg {
    // path to example image used as "game" background
    private static final String IMG_PATH = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/"
            + "wikipedia/commons/7/76/Jump_%27n_Bump.png";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        // get the "game" background image, or exit if fail
        BufferedImage img = null;
        try {
            URL imgUrl = new URL(IMG_PATH);
            img = ImageIO.read(imgUrl);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        // pass "game" image into main JPanel so that it will be drawn
        DeMainPanel mainPanel = new DeMainPanel(img);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Dialog Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(mainPanel); // add main JPanel to JFrame
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

```
// main JPanel
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class DeMainPanel extends JPanel {
    private BufferedImage img; // background image

    // JButton action that shows the JDialog and darkens the glasspane
    private PauseAction pauseAction = new PauseAction("Pause");

    public DeMainPanel(BufferedImage img) {
        super();
        this.img = img;
        add(new JButton(pauseAction));
    }

    // draw the "game" background image within the JPanel if not null
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (img != null) {
            g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);
        }
    }

    // size this JPanel to match the image's size
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (isPreferredSizeSet() || img == null) {
            return super.getPreferredSize();
        }
        int width = img.getWidth();
        int height = img.getHeight();
        return new Dimension(width, height);
    }
}
```

```
// Action / ActionListener for JButton -- shows JDialog and darkens glasspane
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class PauseAction extends AbstractAction {
    private static final int ALPHA = 175; // how much see-thru. 0 to 255
    private static final Color GP_BG = new Color(0, 0, 0, ALPHA);
    private DeDialogPanel deDialogPanel = new DeDialogPanel();  // jpanel shown in JDialog

    public PauseAction(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // comp is our JButton
        Component comp = (Component) e.getSource();
        if (comp == null) {
            return;
        }

        // create our glass pane
        JPanel glassPane = new JPanel() {
            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                // magic to make it dark without side-effects
                g.setColor(getBackground());
                g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
                super.paintComponent(g);
            }
        };
        // more magic below
        glassPane.setOpaque(false); 
        glassPane.setBackground(GP_BG);     

        // get the rootpane container, here the JFrame, that holds the JButton
        RootPaneContainer win = (RootPaneContainer) SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(comp);
        win.setGlassPane(glassPane);  // set the glass pane
        glassPane.setVisible(true);  // and show the glass pane

        // create a *modal* JDialog
        JDialog dialog = new JDialog((Window)win, "", ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        dialog.getContentPane().add(deDialogPanel);  // add its JPanel to it
        dialog.setUndecorated(true); // give it no borders (if desired)
        dialog.pack(); // size it
        dialog.setLocationRelativeTo((Window) win); // ** Center it over the JFrame **
        dialog.setVisible(true);  // display it, pausing the GUI below it

        // at this point the dialog is no longer visible, so get rid of glass pane
        glassPane.setVisible(false);

    }
}
```

```
// JPanel shown in the modal JDialog above
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class DeDialogPanel extends JPanel {
    private static final Color BG = new Color(123, 63, 0);

    public DeDialogPanel() {
        JLabel pausedLabel = new JLabel("PAUSED");
        pausedLabel.setForeground(Color.ORANGE);
        JPanel pausedPanel = new JPanel();
        pausedPanel.setOpaque(false);
        pausedPanel.add(pausedLabel);

        setBackground(BG);
        int eb = 15;
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(eb, eb, eb, eb));
        setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1, 10, 10));
        add(pausedPanel);
        add(new JButton(new FooAction("RESUME")));
        add(new JButton(new FooAction("RESTART")));
        add(new JButton(new FooAction("EXIT TO MAP")));
    }

    // simple action -- all it does is to make the dialog no longer visible
    private class FooAction extends AbstractAction {
        public FooAction(String name) {
            super(name);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Component comp = (Component) e.getSource();
            Window win = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(comp);
            win.dispose();  // here -- dispose of the JDialog
        }
    }
}
```

The GUI looks like this initially:

[image]

but then when the dialog shows and the glass pane is darkened, it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: `dialog.setUndecorated(true)` is more than desired, it disallows the user to move it around. Also, the dialog should be modal.

Comment: @user1803551: thanks for your comments, and indeed you're right on both points. To make the dialog modal, I used one of the JDialog constructors above that accepted a `ModalityType` enum as one of its parameters, and the underlying window as its other parameter -- `new JDialog((Window)win, "", ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL)`. Being modal means that the underlying GUI cannot interact with the user until the dialog is no longer visible. Again, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Oh, didn't see that you set the modality in the constructor already, sorry. Was looking for `setModal` (or `setModalityType`).

Comment: @user1803551: no problem as I've posted quite a lot of code, probably a little more than I should have. The trickiest part for me though was to partially darken the glass pane without causing side effects. All the ways that I would usually do this resulted in image artifacts showing up on the glass pane, and so I had to search out, learn, and use camickr's solution.

Comment: DontKnowMuchBut appreciate the full explanation and run down. I don't think it gets any better than this. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

So after about a month of working on my game I was drawn to this post once again. I implemented part of my game with what DontKnowMuchButGettingBetter's way and also implemented this by just adding the components to the GlassPane so to speak (Made a JPanel, set it to be GlassPane, did whatever on that Panel)...

The later implementation (GlassPane), isn't the best way to go about this because then you can't use the glass pane for other useful things.

I came back to my original idea to use a JLayeredPane. Having different Components on different levels and working off that. My issue before was that when components were getting repainted, the components in the backer layers were over painting the ones in the front layer.

Well I just came across a method called isOptimizedDrawingEnabled()... By making this method always return false for the JLayeredPane I was able to achieve what I wanted.